# Nesting routing in any order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-routing

In the web app I'm currently working on, the data is initially present as a table showing SKU data from a database.  We have three warehouses, a set of filters that we'd like to implement, and a set of sorts we'd like to implement.

Is there a way that we can implement something like this:

```
../sort/:sortcol/:sort_type/..

../warehouse/:warehouse/..

../filter/:filter_id/..
```

so that if a user just does `/warehouse/A`, it returns everything contained in just Warehouse A.  If a user goes to `/warehouse/A/sort/sku/asc`, it gets the data from Warehouse A, then sorts it by SKU in ascending order.  I'd also like for these to be available in ANY order - that is, sort can be called before or after filter.  How would one do this?

Comment: It might simplify to keep the sorting out of the path and use query parameters for that? e.g. `/warehouse/A?sort=sku&direction=asc`?

Comment: it's simpler, but I was curious if there was a way to do this, partially because I like it a little better, but also partially because I want to learn new things on this.

Also, I was hoping to basically just write the warehouse, sort, and filter things once then call them, is that still manageable with this method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
  resources :warehouses do
    get 'sort/*sortcol/*sort_type', to: 'warehouses#index'
  end
  get 'sort/*sortcol/*sort_type/warehouses/*warehouse_id', to: 'warehouses#index'
```

Which should give you something like:

```
                GET    /warehouses/:warehouse_id/sort/*sortcol/*sort_type(.:format)  warehouses#index
     warehouses GET    /warehouses(.:format)                                         warehouses#index
                POST   /warehouses(.:format)                                         warehouses#create
  new_warehouse GET    /warehouses/new(.:format)                                     warehouses#new
 edit_warehouse GET    /warehouses/:id/edit(.:format)                                warehouses#edit
      warehouse GET    /warehouses/:id(.:format)                                     warehouses#show
                PATCH  /warehouses/:id(.:format)                                     warehouses#update
                PUT    /warehouses/:id(.:format)                                     warehouses#update
                DELETE /warehouses/:id(.:format)                                     warehouses#destroy
                GET    /sort/*sortcol/*sort_type/warehouses/*warehouse_id(.:format)  warehouses#index
```

Then you could do some params checking in `warehouse_controller#index` to determine whether to do a sorted index or a regular index.

As a side note, I believe the convention is to use `warehouses/:id` when working with a single warehouse. Not `warehouse/:id`. You can see this in the named routes under `warehouse_path`.

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more flexible, to be honest - something where `/sort/sku/asc/warehouse/a` and `/warehouse/a/sort/sku/asc` are equivalent.  If it's not manageable, that's ok, I was just curious and hopeful :)